# CKEditor Browse Server Button

Tags: ckeditor

Looking for a very simple way to disable/remove the CKEditor "browse server" button when using the Link toolbar button without disabling the "browser server" button when using the Image toolbar button.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go the other way round and just enable it only in the dialog windows where it's needed? There are dedicated configuration options for that, read more in the [Adding File Manager Scripts for Selected Dialog Windows](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_manager_configuration-section-adding-file-manager-scripts-for-selected-dialog-windows) section of the documentation.

So, for example, to enable it just for the Image dialog window, use the [config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserImageBrowseUrl) and [config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-filebrowserImageUploadUrl) properties, like in the example below:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/browser/browse.php?type=Images',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/uploader/upload.php?type=Images'
});
```

Comment: I'm ok with the image browsing.  It's the link browsing button I wish to disable without disabling the image browsing button.

Comment: Like I said above, instead of *disabling* it for Links, *enable* it only for Images. There are different configuration options for that, please refer to the documentation and example quoted above.